# Establish relationship between Picklist in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

My problem is something similar to the question already asked in the forum https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16867/picklist-dependent-on-2-controlling-picklist. However, I am looking for more concrete solution. My case in brief, I want to devise a picklist A which is the primary picklist. For some values of A among different values being present in B, some are applicable(For example state city relationship). Based on the values of A & B applicable values of C will be displayed. Please provide me with a detailed solution of how it may be achieved.

Tried searching google and looking into dependant and controlling picklist in Salesforce.

NA

NA

Comment: As this is a very Salesforce-specific issue, you are better off asking in Salesforce SE.

Comment: @identigral, can you please guide me as to how to move the post to Salesforce SE?

Comment: Delete it here and post it over there.